# Detect zoom level on all modern browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zooming

I was wondering if there's a way to detect the page zoom level which is supported by all modern browsers. I've already tried this:
[how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers)

but unfortunately it is not fully compatible with all the browser I tried.

Is there a more general method, or a jquery library to achieve that?

Comment: Did you had any luck?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect page zoom level in all modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers)

Comment: This might be helpful: https://www.sitelint.com/blog/detect-browser-zoom-level/

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what your goal. If you only need the current scaling you can use:

```
window.devicePixelRatio
```

But the value is not equal to the zoom level on all devices because on HighDPI devices (4k Display, Smartphone, …) the start value is not 1 because there is a default zoom to compensate the higher pixel resolution.

Comment: The value returned from this is unaltered by browser zoom level changes in Safari (10.1)

Comment: That methods is if not good as it behaves in weird and unpredictabe ways accross browser and their respective versions